# Need help regarding refresh token mechanims

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt

I have a client facing React native application.
I'm using JWT for authentication with quickly expiring access tokens(10m) & long lasting refresh tokens (7d).
I have two servers, one for auth & one for fetching other things.
ex: `server.com/auth`, `server.com/activities`
My question is, how to have a good refresh mechanism here ? 
Ex: If a user logs in after 2 days and queries an API through my app, how should I send him the new access token back (using his refresh token) - keeping in mind my auth server is at a separate location ? 
The obvious solution I see here is to contact `/auth` from `/activities`, get the new tokens and send the new tokens in the header of the response, while on the client side keep checking for new tokens in the header & saving them if present.
Is there a better solution than this ? Is this even a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

An perhaps better option is to look at using the Backend For Frontend (a.k.a BFF) pattern to secure SPA applications.

See

- [Backend For Frontend Authentication Pattern with Auth0 and ASP.NET Core](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/)
- [The BFF Pattern (Backend for Frontend): An Introduction](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)
- [Securing SPAs using the BFF Pattern (once and for all)](https://blog.duendesoftware.com/posts/20210326_bff/)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, and as far as I know is what most people do is to have your API (/activities) respond with 403 if the access token is expired. The frontend should catch these responses and then ask the authorization server for a new access token based on the refresh token you have. The AS will respond with a fresh access token, which the frontend can now use to send to the API. Usually this exchange will happen automatically and the frontend will eventually retry calling the API with the new access token.

If the refresh token happens to be expired, then the authorization server will respond with a 403, which is a signal to the frontend app that it should ask the user to log in again.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the whole process pretty slow & network sensitive, considering my access tokens have a very short lifespan ? Almost every other call would have to contact auth from the frontend again.
Having my backend directly call auth on access token expiry (but a valid refresh token) will make the process resilient to client's network don't you think ?
(I'm new to all this so please bear with me)

Comment: It's tempting to implement it as you described, but it can introduce some problems. You start complicating things - now you have two clients (frontend and backend) which operate on the same set of tokens (which should not normally happen). Also, you introduce side effects to your backend calls. You suddenly have to be aware of the fact that maybe backend will return new tokens, and so on. If resources are your concern then I would go with a BFF solution proposed by Tore, and use session cookies on frontend instead of tokens.